# How to get address from json object which gets div from google search

Tags: java, json, html, htmlunit

when i type a company name in Google, and press enter, it will give a right side  of image of the company and address CEO etc details.

My java code uses `HTMLUnit` and gets this div and is converted to json object. In this json object address of the company is present. Let let me know how to get this address from the json output. It is not a TAG, it has come from right side  of Google search.

My code is here.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNodeList;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;


public class googleHTMLUnit
{

    public static final String TEST_XML_STRING = null;
    public static final int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 0;


    public void homePage_Firefox() throws Exception
    {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        String searchparameter = "jn planetarium bangalore";
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=" + searchparameter  + "&btnG=");
        DomNodeList<DomElement> button = page.getElementsByTagName("a");
        HtmlPage page2 = null;


        for(int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++ )
        {
            //System.out.println(button.get(i).getTextContent());
            if(button.get(i).getTextContent().contains("Google review"))
            {
                //System.out.println(button.get(i).getTextContent());
                Iterable<HtmlElement> buttontobeclicked = button.get(i).getHtmlElementDescendants();
                for(HtmlElement test:buttontobeclicked)
                {
                    System.out.println(test.getNodeValue());
                    System.out.println("inside for ");
                    page2 = test.click();
                    //page2 = test.click();
                    //Event test1 = new Event();
                    //page2 = test.fireEvent(test1);
                    //Object page3 = page2.getJavaScriptResult();
                    //page3.toString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("href " + button.get(i));
        }
        //System.out.println("href " + button);
        //button.click();
        //System.out.println("After click " + page2.asXml());
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
        //System.out.println(page2.asXml());
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(page.asXml());
        System.out.println(xmlJSONObj.toString());

    }




    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            //System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/output-file.html")));
            //System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/output-file.html")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        googleHTMLUnit test = new googleHTMLUnit();
        try
        {
            test.homePage_Firefox();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

The output of this will be like this in json object, I want to get address and phone number which is present in this json object. How to do this.

```
"span":{"content":[":",", Raj Bhavan Road,",", Karnataka -Get contact address
```

Comment: please post full Json response. From your example we don't see address or phone. Thanks

Comment: Hi Maxim thanks for reply, i tried to put full json respone but it exceeds 30000 chars, so stack is not taking it, My end aim would be like a lead generation tool (my code) when user enters a company name it should fetch the details that are present in google search in right side div. How to do this in java code ?

Comment: post only relevant part with address/phone, nothing to do with example you posted

Comment: When we type any company name in google search and enter, most of the times in the right side of the screen we get some information snippet of the company, i want to capture those details. How to do this in java ?

Sorry i am not getting what to post in json object, that you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the JSON object as below and fetch the address and phone number

```
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) xmlJSONObj.get("content");
Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Teeg. It worked. Now I want to pull google reviews, I am using java HTML unit. I am not able to simulate javascript onclick behind google review. For example type "vidyarthi bhavan" in google search, in the right side of screen you will get snippet and i am pulling all info except google reviews. The problem is when i press on google reviews, it is not a new page, it is just a pop up kind of a thing. I searched a lot but not getting, Pls let me know how to pull reviews from google using java code.